# What Does This Convey?

Tags: 16.04, encoding

So, I was messing around and setting up an mpich cluster, and whilst following this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) that I found very handy, I ran the C file that I ran gave me such a nasty output that it was actually quite shocking in real life.

Just kidding, but it was rather odd what it gave me. 
it was something along the lines of

[image]

does anyone understand, at least, what might be happening here? I went from thirty two bit to 64 bit, and I reproduced this error.

Comment: Did you compile the source code from the tutorial verbatim?

Comment: Yea, I find it weird because I don't normally use C++, I write python, and bash/batch. So I may have freaked out a bit when seeing this.